# Flutter release apk on Google Play fails with 'not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent'

Tags: android, flutter, store, playback, jdwp

Searched all over the internet, haven't found the solution.

So, the problem is: flutter app perfectly works during debug on Android. Once published to App Store there is black screen. I was managed to find log message for error : - 'not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent'.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I don't know flutter or any mobile development but it looks like you left the debugging stuff enabled in production.